# serverside validation for a sign in form

Tags: php, html, authentication

```html
 <form method="POST" onsubmit=" return formSubmit() " action="log-it-reports.php">
                <div class="userimage">
                    <img class="userlogo" src="image/userlogo.png" alt="Picture- User Profile picture">
                </div><br>
                <div class="error" id= "errorMsg"></div><br>
                <div class="error" id= "errorMsg1"></div>
                 <div class="field">
                    <label class="stafflabel">  Staff Name  </label>
                    <input class="area" placeholder="staffmember or admin" onclick=" return userValidation()" onchange=" return userValidation()" id="staff" name="staffname" type="text" value="<?php echo $staffname;?>" >
                 </div> <br>
                 <div class="error" id= "errorMsg2"></div>
                 <div class="field">
                    <label class="passlabel">   Password    </label>
                    <input class="area" placeholder="password" onclick=" return userValidation()" onchange=" return userValidation()" id="pass" name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>" >
                 </div><br>
                
                    <div class="checkbox">
                       <input type="checkbox" class="remember-me">
                       <label class="remember" for="remember-me">Remember me         </label>   
                       <a class="pass-link" href="#"> Forgot password?</a>
                    </div><br><br><br>
                    
                 <div class="field">
                    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign in">
                 </div> <br>
                 <div class="account-link">
                    Didn't create an account yet? <a href="#">Create Account</a>
                 </div>
            </form>
```

I would like to validate a sign in form with predefined usernames (admin, staffmember) and passwords (heretohelp!456 , letmein!123) in the serverside using php, my approach to it is using if statements to check for the posted input , firstly, is this a good approach or there is a better way to do it ? secondly, i'm getting an error in my code that says : syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)
the brackets i have seem to match, the error shows in lines : 15, 32 of this snippet

```
<?php

$staffname = $_POST['staff'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$error = "";

// validating staff member:
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($staffname == "staffmember") {
        if ($password == "letmein!123") {
            $error = "" ;
        }
        // redirect to the logs report page when successful
        header("location: log-it-reports.php");
        else {
            $error = "* You have entered a wrong password!";
        }
    }
    else {
        $error = "You have entered a wrong staff name!";
    }
}

// validating admin:
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($staffname == "admin") {
        if ($password == "heretohelp!456") {
            $error = "" ;
        }
        // redirect to the logs report page when successful
        header("location: update-log-reports.php");
        else {
            $error = "* You have entered a wrong password!";
        }
    }
    else {
        $error = "You have entered a wrong staff name!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a `}` before the first `else`. Actually, there are multiple issues with your `{` and `}`

Comment: @M.Eriksson no he's not, that if is closed one line before.

Comment: @callback - Yes they do since they have a `header()`-statement after that `if`. That menas that the `else` would be for the second `if`. But it's not the only issues with the braces and with the logic.

Comment: 1. Check if username and password exist. 2 Check if they are string formatted. 3. Check lengths. 4. Make it safe for query checking DB or inserting and you good.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, could you pleas clarify why the header() is an issue, and what i could do to fix it ?

Comment: It's an issue because you then follow it with an `else`. You can't have an `else` which doesn't immediately follow the closing bracket of an `if`. It would appear to make more logical sense, in this case, if the `header` command was inside the `if`, since it looks like you want to redirect only when the password matched?

Comment: Security note: you'll rarely find applications which tell the user whether they entered a wrong username, or a wrong password. The most secure ones will simply say that the login was unsuccessful, without saying which credential was wrong. This is because if, for example, someone is trying to guess logins, and they happen to enter a username which exists in your system, if you tell them it's only the password which is wrong, they now know the username really exists and they have a much easier path to trying to hack into that account.

Comment: @ADyson, yeah what im trying to do is to send the admin to a page different that the staffmember's page, both go to different pages,  thats why i needed the header, so you are saying i should include the header inside the if above the Else ? by the way, thats a smart security note, it makes so much sense :)

Comment: Yes the header should be inside the if...otherwise (if it wasn't crashing) it would redirect regardless of whether the password was valid or not

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your code, so at least it is somewhat DRY and solves your syntax issues as pointed out by people in the comments.

Any decent PHP editor (use Vscode with the [inteliphense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) plugin if you need something free) will show you syntax errors when you code and help you with PHP syntax.  If you do use it, make sure you read the instructions and disable the default php plugins as per it's instructions.

```
<?php
// validating staff member:
$staffname = $_POST['staff'] ?? '';
$password = $_POST['pass'] ?? '';
$error = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($staffname == "staffmember") {
        if ($password == "letmein!123") { 
            // redirect to the logs report page when successful
            header("location: log-it-reports.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            $error = "* You have entered a wrong password!";
        }
    } else if ($staffname == "admin") {
        if ($password == "heretohelp!456") {
            // redirect to the logs report page when successful
            header("location: update-log-reports.php");
            exit;
        } else {
            $error = "* You have entered a wrong password!";
        }
    } else {
        $error = "You have entered a wrong staff name!";
    }
    // Maybe you want to actually send the error back to the browser if there was one?
    echo "<p>$error</p>";
}
```

Pro tip:  Your scripts should omit the php end tag ie. `?>`.  You never need it at the end of any PHP script, and having it included scripts can create output when you don't want or expect it. You only need to use the end tag when you have a script that has a mixture of PHP and html, and you are going in and out of PHP blocks.  If PHP is the last thing in a script, then leave off the `?>`

Something I added for your $_POST assignments:  The [Null coalescing operator](https://riptutorial.com/php/example/7164/null-coalescing-operator-----).  This handles the problem of someone submitting your form but leaving off either of the required fields.

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip, @gview.  i tried out your code as well, however i get logged in without even writing inputs .. i would add a code snippet above to show you how my form is structured.

Comment: There is no way my code "logs in" without input.  So i'm not sure what that means within the context of your other code. These are parts that have to be assembled correctly.  Also just to be clear your code doesn't have a concept of authentication.  I just takes the inputs and checks for string equivalence of 2 username/password combos, then redirects to another page.  If I know the page I can navigate to it.  To create actual authentication you need to add PHP sessions, and have a routine in your secured pages that denies access to the secured pages unless there is login.

Comment: One way to do that would be to set a session variable like $_SESSION['username'] just before you redirect using header() in the code I provided.  Your php scripts need to start_session() at the top, and then your secured pages would be able to include `if (empty($_SESSION['username']) { header("location: login.php"); exit; }`    Read through the [php manual session docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session) for more info